# Issue with ":target" selector in jquery 1.10.2 and chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I'm using jQuery for selecting an element that is targeted (using `#test` in the url) and I'm getting a browser-dependent behavior with it.

The code:

```
### test.html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="[path_to_]/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">Hello world</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert($(":target").html());
        $(":target").fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) but this requires the url (which I tried but I was not able to make it work in jsFiddle).

Now, if I open the page `test.html#test`...

- with firefox 24.0, it alerts an `Hello world` and
  fades correctly.
- with Chrome 29.0.1547.76, it alerts an `undefined`, and
  doesn't fade.

I'm using Mac OS X in both.

What am I doing wrong? is this a "feature"?

Comment: Just as a test, if you wrap your alert and animation in a setTimeout, say, 1 second later, does it work?

Comment: A timeout of just 1 ms workaround the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug, you could workaround it with either using the hash as the selector:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    alert($(location.hash).html());
    $(location.hash).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000);
  });
```

or doing a while until your element exists or some time is reached like Kevin mentioned in the comment.

EDIT: bug report (there are a few duplicates) http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14135